# ARM - How to preserve r9 register with armcc

Tags: arm, eabi, armcc

Reading ARM AAPCS (ARM EABI), I've found :
*The role of register r9 is platform specific. A virtual platform may assign any role to this register and must document this usage. For example, it may designate it as the static base (SB) in a position-independent data model, or it may designate it as the thread register (TR) in an environment with thread-local storage. The usage of this register may require that the value held is persistent across all calls. A virtual platform that has no need for such a special register may designate r9 as an additional callee-saved variable register, v6.*

I'd like to use r9 as a PID holder for my specific avionics preemptible OS, but I can't figure out how to preserve it : armcc C compiler always uses it as a variable register, so its value always changes through applicative SW.

Any idea ? Is it possible with armcc ? GCC ? DIAB ?...

Thanks for any help.

Regards

Christophe

Answer (score 2):

For ARMCC you could try

```
--global_reg=6
```

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/CHDBJGCH.html

Answer (score 1):

I answer to mysellf :
for GCC, -ffixed-r9 could be used.

[GCC online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html)

And for Windriver Diab compiler :

"#pragma global_register identifier=register"

(to be included in every files)